# reload collection view by press back bar button item

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uinavigationbar, backbarbuttonitem

I have a `collectionView` in my app that when the user taps one cell of it, the `collectionView` will reload data, in detail, I have an album that it could contain another album when user choose one of them it shows albums inside of that.

Now I want when user click on `backBarButton` the past data appears on `collectionView` (super-albums), but now `backbarButton` shows the past VC.

I use navigationController and show module segues between VCs.

**Q:** How should I implement that?

Comment: Please show some code, what have you tried?

Comment: @user1000 I didn't have any ideas to start that, but now I think I can create segue from the VC to itself, Is that right way ?

Answer (score 0):

If your changing view on collection cell press. you can reload the collection view on **viewWillAppear**.

Comment: I want reload collectionView on cell press, AND get the past data on collectionView on backBarButton press, something like stack, first I push some data on the collection then push another when the backBarButton clicked the last data should be popped

Comment: Do you have a model structure? if yes please share a screnshot, model structure and collection view data source